# Trying to get acceleration using Accelerometer And/Or Gyroscope

Tags: react-native, expo, accelerometer, sensors, gyroscope

I am creating a project on react-native (I'm a newbie)
I'm trying to understand the data I'm getting from this code

[Expo documentation (code available)](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/accelerometer/)

Main goal to get the acceleration and direction of the phone movement .
Thank you in advance for any tips .

Comment: I think that data is (x, y, z). By taking the coordinates of 2 positions in spacetime, you can calculate direction (x2-x1, y2-y1, z2-z1). For speed and acceleration you should take into account the delta Time that has passed.

Comment: I think the data given by  the accelerometer is for the phone position not direction. For example if you throw the phone in the air you would get how the phone was rolling in the air not the path it took . I still confused because of all Law of motion formulas and different data received from both Gyroscope and Accelerometer .